# C++ Deallocation after push_back to static vector

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

In the following code, I try to implement a cached singleton pattern (every Multiplication(n) shall only exist once).

```
  vector<Multiplication>& Multiplication::cacheVector() {
    static vector<Multiplication> cache({Multiplication(0)});

    return cache;
  }

  const Multiplication& Multiplication::getInstance(unsigned int order) {

    while (order >= cacheVector().size()) {
      cacheVector().push_back(Multiplication(cacheVector().size()));      
    }

    return cacheVector()[order];      
  }
```

The problem is: When I try to use the cached Multiplication instances, I get a segfault. Valgrind tells me, that I invoke invalid reads, because the data was free'd in the getInstance function:

```
==5471==    by 0x4C2054D: std::_Vector_base<tnp::Multiplication, std::allocator<tnp::Multiplication> >::_M_deallocate(tnp::Multiplication*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:174)
==5471==    by 0x4C2029D: _ZNSt6vectorIN3tnp14MultiplicationESaIS1_EE19_M_emplace_back_auxIJS1_EEEvDpOT_ (stl_vector.h:430)
==5471==    by 0x4C1FFDF: _ZNSt6vectorIN3tnp14MultiplicationESaIS1_EE12emplace_backIJS1_EEEvDpOT_ (vector.tcc:101)
==5471==    by 0x4C1EE9F: std::vector<tnp::Multiplication, std::allocator<tnp::Multiplication> >::push_back(tnp::Multiplication&&) (stl_vector.h:920)
==5471==    by 0x4C1DF52: tnp::Multiplication::getInstance(unsigned int) (multiplication.cpp:83)
```

Multiplication has no own copy constructor and those fields:

```
  class Multiplication { 

    const unsigned int order;
    const vector<Product> valueSum;
    const vector<Product> partialDerSum;
    const vector<Multiplication>& instances;
```

(where instances is, except for order==0, a back-reference to the cache vector), the deallocation is probably happening to the valueSum and partialDerSum vectors.

So why does C++ do a deallocation of my fresh Multiplication instance? Shouldn't it just copy it into the vector?
I would like to avoid any explicit heap allocations, as pointer indirection would impose some performance penalties further down the road.

Comment: Are you storing references or pointers to the cached values? These will be invalidated when the cache vector grows. You could prevent that by using `deque`, which never moves its elements, rather than `vector`; or by storing copies, if the cost of copying isn't too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't pointed to exact line which causes segfault, so just my wild guess:

Probably you stored a reference to Multiplication instance somewhere and after that added new item(s) to vector that led to vector reallocation of it's internal memory and so your reference points to deallocated memory

Comment: Thanks. That's it. Obviously, I need to access the multiplication instances via their index instead of a const reference.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer to why it crashes, rather an explanation to these questions:

> So why does C++ do a deallocation of my fresh Multiplication instance? Shouldn't it just 
>   copy it into the vector?

In fact it does copy or move.

Let's describe this line a bit:

```
cacheVector().push_back(Multiplication(cacheVector().size()));
```

The `Multiplication(cacheVector().size())` is allocated somewhere, but the memory of your `cacheVector` is not at the same place, so the vector copy or move (here it will certainly be a move) the data from your `Multiplication` while creating the instance in the `cacheVector`.

[Here is a small example](http://ideone.com/UwMYRS) that can help you grasp this.

You see that there is a call to the "normal" constructor then a call to the **move** constructor. The compile then has to delete the instance that was moved to the vector, so it does call the destructor on the instance that was allocated with the "normal" constructor.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for the explanation. Just out of curiosity: Is there a way to allocate an object directly inside the vectors memory to avoid that move?

Comment: @choeger Not that I am aware of. [Even initializer list use copy](http://ideone.com/ROWD5s)...